# Display row numbers in ListView UWP

Tags: c++, listview, uwp

I'm looking for a solution to display row numbers for every element in ListView. What's more, the row numbers need to be updated after some element is deleted from the list or when the elements are moved to another positions. I'm using UWP (C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display row numbers in a `ListView`, we suggest you to use data binding. You could refer to the document: [XAML controls; bind to a C++/WinRT property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property) and [XAML items controls; bind to a C++/WinRT collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-collection) for detailed code about data binding.

Take the project `Bookstore` implemented in the above documents as an example, we need to change the content of each item in a `ListView` by using [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview#simple-listview-data-template), and update the index of each item when the `IObservableVector` instance(which is the data binding source of the `ListView`) changes by adding the `IObservableVector<T>.VectorChanged` event.

For example:

1. Add a property representing the index of each item in the `ListView`.

BookSku.idl

```
    runtimeclass BookSku : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ……
        Int16 Index;
    }
```

BookSku.h

```
struct BookSku : BookSkuT<BookSku>
{
    ……
    int16_t Index();
    void Index(int16_t value);

private:
    ……
    int16_t m_index = 0;
};
```

BookSku.cpp

```
int16_t BookSku::Index()
{
    return m_index;
}
void BookSku::Index(int16_t value)
{
    if (m_index != value)
    {
        m_index = value;
        m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Index" });
    }
}
```

2. Initiate the `Index` property when initiate the `m_bookSkus` , and add the [VectorChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.iobservablevector-1.vectorchanged?view=winrt-19041) event for `m_bookSkus` to update the index when the items of `m_bookSkus` changes.

BookstoreViewModel.cpp

```
    BookstoreViewModel::BookstoreViewModel()
    {
        m_bookSkus = winrt::single_threaded_observable_vector<Bookstore::BookSku>();
        m_bookSkus.VectorChanged([](IObservableVector<Bookstore::BookSku> const& sender, IVectorChangedEventArgs const& args) {

        for (int16_t i = 0; i < sender.Size(); i++)
        {
             auto item = sender.GetAt(i);
             item.Index(i+1);
        }

        });

    int16_t index=0;
    
    m_bookSku = winrt::make<Bookstore::implementation::BookSku>(L"Title1");
    index = m_bookSkus.Size() + 1;
    m_bookSku.Index(index);

    m_bookSkus.Append(m_bookSku);

    m_bookSku = winrt::make<Bookstore::implementation::BookSku>(L"Title2");
    index = m_bookSkus.Size() + 1;
    m_bookSku.Index(index);

    m_bookSkus.Append(m_bookSku);

    m_bookSku = winrt::make<Bookstore::implementation::BookSku>(L"Title3");
    index = m_bookSkus.Size() + 1;
    m_bookSku.Index(index);

    m_bookSkus.Append(m_bookSku);
}
```

3. Display the index in each item of the `ListView` by using `DataTemplate` in XAML.

MainPage.xaml

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MainViewModel.BookSkus}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:BookSku">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Index,Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

You could refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate?view=winrt-19041) for more information about DataTemplate, and refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/handle-events) for more information about handing events by using delegates in C++/WinRT.